# VS Code task process stdout/stderr

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I'm attempting to write some test for a VS Code extension.

The extension basically creates some tasks, using `ShellExecution` to run a local executable file, for example:

```js
new Task(
  definition,
  folder,
  name,
  source,
  new ShellExecution('./runme', { cwd })
);
```

I would like to be able to test the shell process, but don't have access to this process and so cannot attach to any of the output streams nor get the exit code.

In my tests, I execute the task like so: `await vscode.tasks.executeTask(task);` which runs successfully regardless of the exit code of the process created by `ShellExecution`.

Is there any way I can get access to the child process generated from executing a task?

Answer (score 1):

With Node.js' `child_process` this is simple to do. I use it to [run an external Java jar](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/SourceContext.ts#L671) and capture its output to get the errors. The main part is:

```
            let java = child_process.spawn("java", parameters, spawnOptions);

            let buffer = "";
            java.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
                let text = data.toString();
                if (text.startsWith("Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:")) {
                    let endOfInfo = text.indexOf("\n");
                    if (endOfInfo == -1) {
                        text = "";
                    } else {
                        text = text.substr(endOfInfo + 1, text.length);
                    }
                }

                if (text.length > 0) {
                    buffer += "\n" + text;
                }
            });

            java.on("close", (code) => {
                let parser = new ErrorParser(dependencies);
                if (parser.convertErrorsToDiagnostics(buffer)) {
                    thisRef.setupInterpreters(options.outputDir);
                    resolve(fileList);
                } else {
                    reject(buffer); // Treat this as non-grammar error (e.g. Java exception).
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes this is fairly straight-ward to do if you have control of the creation of the process. The problem with using `ShellExecution` as part of a `vscode.Task` is that the process is not exposed (as far as i can tell).